# Why is the Mean Average Percentage Error(mape) extremely high?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have obtained code from [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)

I modified the **model.compile()** function to add ***mape*** metrics to find out the Mean Absolute Percentage Error. After running the code, the **mape** at every epoch comes so huge, considering it as a percentage metric. Am I missing something obvious or is the output right?
The output looks like:

```
Epoch 91/100
0s - loss: 0.0103 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1764997.4502
Epoch 92/100
0s - loss: 0.0103 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1765653.4924
Epoch 93/100
0s - loss: 0.0102 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1766505.5107
Epoch 94/100
0s - loss: 0.0102 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1766814.5450
Epoch 95/100
0s - loss: 0.0102 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1767510.8146
Epoch 96/100
0s - loss: 0.0101 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1767686.9054
Epoch 97/100
0s - loss: 0.0101 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1767076.2169
Epoch 98/100
0s - loss: 0.0100 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1767014.8481
Epoch 99/100
0s - loss: 0.0100 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1766592.8125
Epoch 100/100
0s - loss: 0.0100 - mean_absolute_percentage_error: 1766348.6332
```

My code that I ran (which omits the prediction part) goes as follows:

```
import numpy
from numpy import array
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import read_csv
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
        dataX, dataY = [], []
        for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
                a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
                dataX.append(a)
                dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
        return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset
dataframe = read_csv('airlinepassdata.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python', skipfooter=3)
dataset = dataframe.values

#dataset = array([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0])
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam', metrics=['mape'])
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=100, batch_size=50, verbose=2)
```

Comment: What are the average of your ground truth value and the average of your output value ? If your output has values around 0.1 and your ground truth has values very close to 0, then the MSE will be 0.01 and the mean absolute percentage error will be huge, which is what you are observing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved this by setting the fuzz factor epsilon to one with `keras.backend.set_epsilon(1)` before calling the compile.

The hint was in the source code

```
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
diff = K.abs((y_true - y_pred) / K.clip(K.abs(y_true),
                                        K.epsilon(),
                                        None))
return 100. * K.mean(diff, axis=-1)
```

Meaning that, for some unknown reason, the `K.abs(y_true)` term in the MAPE calculation on the training set is lower than the fuzz default (1e-7), so it uses that default value instead, thus the huge numbers.

Comment: Setting K.epsilon to 1 ensures that the denominator is always 1.  In that case, you are not actually doing mean absolute percentage error, you're doing mean absolute error.  ie, you can accomplish the same thing by passing `mae` as the loss function instead of `mape`.

What seems a bit odd to me is that keras is using K.abs() here instead of np.linalg.norm() or some other way of finding the length of the label vector.  Instead of taking the vector difference of predicted vs. true, they are taking the difference in each component, so any that are 0 have infinite loss.  This fails for 1-hot

Comment: I see your point, it'd be a `mae`. I don't know, however, why would the `K.abs(y_true)` return zeroes systematically that are then clipped to  `k.epsilon`, looks like a bug to me.

Comment: In your case, I think it's because you are calling `MinMaxScaler` with a range of 0-1:
`scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)`

This guarantees that the minimum value of y_true will be 0.  Because it can't divide by 0 it has to treat 0 as `K.epsilon`, returning a large number instead of infinity.

Comment: You are right, I am using that standardization, so another solution would be to use mae since in the [0-1] domain is equivalent to mape.

Comment: It does work, but doesn't make sense to use a MAPE statistic for standardized variables. `y_pred=0` doesn't really mean nothing, depending on the standardization it can correspond to the minimum value, the mean, etc.