# Why is the value of my loss so huge? Running an MLP on Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss

I am running a plain Sequential API MLP and encounter a huge loss in my output. I am not sure what is wrong and how to fix. I am using Batch Normalization layers as I read that would help and it actually does but my output is still ridiculous. Any other advice on the architecture is more than welcome.

RMSE loss is about 56000

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=X_train_enc.shape[1], activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(30, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(3, activation='relu'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'linear'))

# # summarize layers
print(model.summary())

from tensorflow.keras import backend
from tensorflow.keras.losses import mean_squared_error

#Creating/Defining our own metrics
def mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = K.abs((y_true - y_pred) / K.clip(K.abs(y_true),
                                        K.epsilon(),
                                        None))
    return 100. * K.mean(diff, axis=-1)
tf.keras.backend.set_epsilon(1) #https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49729522/why-is-the-mean-average-percentage-errormape-extremely-high


def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
    return backend.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred))

#def rmse(y_true, y_pred):
#    return backend.sqrt(backend.mean(backend.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1))

Adamax = tf.keras.optimizers.Adamax(lr=0.02, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)

#Compiling model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss=rmse, metrics=['accuracy',rmse, 'mae', 'mape'])#Metric functions are similar to loss functions, except that the results from evaluating a metric are not used when training the model

# # Creating a checkpoint
filepath="weights-improvement-{epoch:02d}-{val_rmse:.9f}.hdf5"
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_rmse', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='min')
# # monitor = "val_loss", save_best_only=False
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]

history = model.fit(X_train_enc, y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=16, validation_split=0.2681867, callbacks=callbacks_list, verbose=1)
```

Comment: You must never put a `BatchNormalization()` layer _after_ the last dense layer. Probably that is the problem. Additionally, I'm not sure you can put `activation=None`, you may want to omit the argument at all or use `activation='linear'` (both will avoid using an activation function, as it is correct in case of regression).

Comment: Hi Massimo, thank you for your answer. So I made the suggested changes to my code and I still get the a very high loss value. Any other ideas? What should I check next. Thank you in advance!

Comment: A few suggestions: 1). Start with a single dense layer and output layer and try your model. Add complexity after verifying each additional layer works. 2) RMSE is a poor choice for a loss function. if L(x) = sqrt(x) then L'(x) = 1 / 2*sqrt(x); the sqrt in the denominator can cause issue with gradients (i.e. if mse = 0, then you have a zero in the denominator). Just use MSE.

Comment: @gobrewers14  Thank you for your input, I tried your advice with 1 neuron in the first layer, a hidden layer with 3 neurons and and output layer with 1 neuron. I also use mse but my loss is still unbelievable to me at least, "loss: 18811697494.5300". Is there any case where a loss could take such a value? Could it have anything to do with my dataset?